# Laser Basics: Why does gain scale with wavelength to the power of 5

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, laser, photon-emission

I've read numerous times that the gain cross section for laser materials (e.g. Titanium Sapphire) is proportional to the fluorescence spectrum multiplied by the wavelength to the power of 5. 
(e.g. in recent research papers: start of Section 3 in: https://www.osapublishing.org/oe/abstract.cfm?uri=oe-25-6-6954)

However, I can't find a solid explanation for this phenomena: why is it that the gain scales with wavelength^5?

And given the strong relationship between gain and wavelength, this suggests that longer wavelength lasers should, in general, be easier to build, right?

Any insight or good references would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Does this help: https://www.rp-photonics.com/fuchtbauer_ladenburg_equation.html

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_coefficients#Stimulated_emission the einstein relation gives a$\lambda^3$ depedence. The additional $\lambda^2$ comes from the Lorentzian linewidth dependence at large wavelengths. 
Yes long wavelength are easier to lase hence the maser was built before the laser

Comment: @RonanTarikDrevon That looks like an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Thank you. If you'd like to post as an answer - I can accept this as the solution. If possible, perhaps you might be able to explain the origin of the two components please? (is there a physical reason why the wavelength cubed results from the Einstein relations?)